# WordPress Plugin styling vs child theme

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, styling

I want to add custom styling for some WP plugin.

I am using WP child theme but my styling is not being detected in front end and its just pulling default style from plugins stylesheet.

What's the hierarchy for this?

Answer (score 0):

The hierarchy is the last style detected in the head section is that who rules.

Sometimes you need to put some styling in pages, so if you use inline style , this is who get the rules.

You can reverse the order putting the !important rule in the style.